# Simultaneously fitting two data sets to two functions is too slow

Tags: functions, fitting, dataset

I have to fit two data sets to two functions(eps1,eps2) with same parameters (w0,f,g)

Initially, I know only one function

```
eps2[w]=f*w0^2*g*w/((w0^2 - w^2)^2 + γ^2*w^2)
```

and with Kramers-Kronig relation:

```
eps1[w]=epsinf + 1/Pi*NIntegrate[eps2[W]/(W-w),
  {W,-Infinity,Infinity},Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> Automatic];
```

So i have two functions eps1 and eps2.

Model:

```
model[index_, w_?NumericQ, epsinf_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, 
  w0_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] :=KroneckerDelta[index - 1]*eps1 +  
  KroneckerDelta[index - 2] *eps2

allData = Join[{1, Sequence @@ #} & /@ re, {2, Sequence @@ #} & /@ im];
```

% re and im are the data sets

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[allData, model[index, w, epsinf, g, w0, 
    f], {{epsinf, 1}, {w0, 3}, {f, 5}, {g, 1}}, {index, w}, MaxIterations -> 1000];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

...It works well but the problem is that it's too slow . I 'am wondering if I could make something to run faster. It takes 20min and if I add more parameters it takes much more.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. It has errors in how the functions are defined. Without some example data, it's not possible to execute the fit.

Comment: I have spell-checked the code to the best of my knowledge in the field and can provide a semi-working example (because even reducing iterations still has the `NonlinearModelFit` work excruciatingly slowly and throw a bunch of errors), as well as generate a set of fake data. I'm still adamant, that OP should take all possible steps to eliminate the KK-transform. Most terms used for fitting optical data _do_ have a closed-form expression for their KK-transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we colleagues, by any chance?

Anyway, there's a well known closed-form expression for `eps1`. Rather than doing the very costly `NIntegrate` to get `eps1` from `eps2` (which is reevaluated many, many times during the execution of `NonLinearModelFit`, I suggest you write down the analytical expression for `eps1`.

For the form of `eps2` that you show here, you can define `eps == eps1 + I eps2`, where `eps[w] == epsinf + w0^2 * f/(w0^2-w^2-I g w)` (I am assuming, that you call what conventionally is known as "delta-epsilon" the variable `f`, and also that the greek gamma in your definition of `eps2` is a typo and should be `g` or vice-versa).

Having eliminated `NIntegrate`, the code should run much faster, but a complex function will require proper adjustment of the `NormFunction` in the fitting procedure (I'm not quite sure, you might have to use `FindFit` instead of `NonLinearModelFit`).

**Edit:**

Even with restricted datasets (I imagine, this would be some reflectivity data) the general idea holds. In the unfortunate case that you have only `eps2` available, there is no use for a Kramers-Kronig transformation as you only have the imaginary part to fit to. In that case just fit as normal, model function with some parameters to known dataset of just `eps2`. Without `NIntegrate` things will go much faster.

Usually, if you have `eps2` in some range, you'll also be able to do a Kramers-Kronig transformation to get `eps1` in a somewhat narrower range. Extra data never hurts, although it will be somewhat ambiguous (high-energy oscillators can contribute an absolute offset, for example). Let `eps_infinity` be an extra fitting parameter, but bear in mind, that it will be unrelated to the "true" value of `eps_infinity`.

Even if you are using functions other than harmonic oscillators, most typical terms for fitting optical data will have a closed-form Kramers-Kronig transformation. If you permit yourself to use extremely arbitrary terms, you might as well just abandon fitting altogether.

Finally, in case you have a term for which you have a closed-form expression for the imaginary part, but not for the real part, there is a trick you should try to employ before resorting to calculating the Kramers-Kronig transformation over and over:

- Let your term (imaginary part) be defined as `term2[x,a,b,c...]` where `x` is frequency, `a` is amplitude, `b,c...` are the remaining parameters.
- Get the Kramers-Kronig transformation at specific values of parameters. That is, define the real part as `term1[x,a0,b0,c0...] == KKTransform[term2[x,a0,b0,c0...]`.
- Kramers-Kronig transformation gives you the real part at a fixed frequency, so you'll have to calculate it for several frequencies, get a list of datapoints of the form of `{x1,term1[x1,a0,b0,c0...]}`. Construct an `InterpolationFunction` from these. Now you have a `Function` object for `term1[x[a0,b0,c0...]`.
- Now you need to study, how it behaves with varying parameters. The first one, amplitude, is easy. You can easily state that `term1[x,a,b0,c0...] == a*term1[x,a0,b0,c0...]/a0`.
- For the remaining parameters grab a pencil and paper and look closely at how the KK-transform integral changes with changing parameters. That will depend on the exact form of your term.
- With some luck you'll arrive at a closed-form or `InterpolationFunction`-form of the KK-transform of your term. That's already much better than `NIntegrate`.

Comment: thank you for answering me ! I am undergraduate physics student !

Comment: Yes, i understand this ,but sometimes only eps2 is given . I dont have always  harmonic oscillators.